The maximum time for SVF conversion
I have looked through the API documentation and the limit quotas documentation,
but there is no information on the maximum time for SVF/SVF2 conversion.
quotas
job_post
I am planning to run a job to check the translation status every 5 minutes, and I want to set a maximum time for the job to run.
I see that a timeout result can be returned, but I don’t know the exact timeout point or detailed information on the time limits.
All Design Automation tasks can set a timeout.

It's not recommended to GET :urn/manifest repeatedly to check the translation status, as this endpoint is not designed for that. Instead, we advise you to use WebHook to achieve that. You can listen to the WebHook events for translation progress and finish status for the Model Derivative service. Here is the tutorial:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook-model-derivative/
Regarding the maximum conversion time for a Model Derivative translation job, I'm sorry, we don't have this information for you.
However, you can safely assume a translation job failed (or get stuck) for some reason once this job doesn't show "status": "success" and  "progress": "complete" in its manifest after submitting the job after 24 HRs.
If so, you can reach out to us for issue reports and troubleshooting using https://aps.autodesk.com/get-help.

The biggest issue is that our system is not public, but we still want to check the history and completion time during file conversion. I know that we can check them indefinitely, but there may be cases where our system encounters issues in updating the results, for example. In such cases, the result might always remain in the "converting" state. So, I just want to know if there is a way to set a maximum time limit for the conversion process.

If the result might always remain in the "converting" state after 24Hrs, you can safely assume the translation job failed and report to us via https://aps.autodesk.com/get-help
